# Restricting users in the same group to view/edit ONLY their own contact details

Tags: wordpress, permissions, acl, user

Restricting users in the same group to ONLY edit their own contact details.

I do not want to create separate group for each contact and then put the restriction. I have many contacts in one group and would like to restrict users from updating each others' details.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have other reasons for doing so, you do not need to give a user access to the back of CiviCRM to edit their own contact details.

In Drupal you can do this by setting any profile with the relevant fields to be **Used For** "View/Edit Drupal User Account".  This profile will then appear on the Drupal account information page when that user is logged in and they can edit their own details.

There is similar functionality for Joomla! and Wordpress, but I can see that the User and Admin guide is somewhat Drupal-centric in this regard and does not specify the equivalent **Used For** option for those. It looks like it **may** be "User account" and that the profile labelled "Name and Address" always has that option selected and is the only profile that can have that option selected in both Joomla! and WordPress.

Alternatively it could be that in Joomla! and WordPress any Contact profile can be exposed through the front-facing web pages to allow logged-in users to edit their own information if you follow the instructions in the [Integrating with Joomla!](http://gitbook.civicrm.org/website-integration/integrating-with-joomla.html) or [Integrating with WordPress](http://gitbook.civicrm.org/website-integration/integrating-with-wordpress.html) sections of our User and Administrator Guide.

(I, too, am somewhat Drupal-centric.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of the relevance of the group in the question. But you can allow anyone to edit their profile by exposing the profile in edit mode.

In the profile listing. click More > Use Profile Create Mode.

Then change the "[create](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/profile/create?gid=1&reset=1)" to "[edit](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/profile/edit?gid=1&reset=1)" in the link and let the users have that link.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response JoAnne and Devejenx.

I had read through all the documents available online as suggested by JoAnne. I even went to try the profile restriction available but with no luck.

I am part of a non-profitable religious organization. We have had numerous issues maintaining user/membership data of the members', and hence decided to give out control to the individuals. With this we can even leverage the other useful tools in CiviCRM like CiviEvent, CiviContribute etc.

We have our site built on Wordpress-CiviCRM.

Will try the hook suggestion and update.

Comment: I don't think this is an answer and should instead be placed as comments elsewhere.

Comment: I don't think my "hook" answer is the right way to go about this: I looked at  the technical challenge of how one would implement the ACL scheme described, rather than the wider issue of why one would want to do that.

Comment: My apologies petednz, since I am new was not aware of the postings. Will ensure to post in the correct section. @davejenx, the idea behind this to prevent user A to update contact details of user B. One solution I figured is to create separate group for each user, which I think is not the correct approach. Any other options that I can check ?